# How to upload a file using zend HttpClient?

Tags: php, rest, file-upload, zend-framework2

I'm using HTTP client. How to attach a file while sending a post request?

Here's my code:

```
function executePost($postdata = [], $full_file_path = ''){
    self::$client = new Zend\Http\Client(null, 
            ['timeout' => 30] // updated to 30 sec
    );
    self::$client->setEncType(Zend\Http\Client::ENC_URLENCODED);

    self::$client->setUri($url);
    self::$client->setMethod($method);
    self::$client->setParameterPost($postdata);

    $response = $client->send();
    Debug::dump($response->getContent(),$label='Response',$echo=true);
}
```

I have tried `$postdata['file_contents'] = '@'.$full_file_path;` but it doesn't help.

Does anyone have an idea on how to attach file with the post data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using that data array try using the designated method called [`setFileUpload`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Client.php#L1017). So in your example it could look like so:

```
$client = new \Zend\Http\Client(null, ['timeout' => 30]);
$client->setUri($url);
$client->setFileUpload($full_file_path, 'file_contents');
$client->setMethod('POST'); // this must be either POST or PUT
$response = $client->send();
```

`setFileUpload` should also set the enc type.

There's a doc section related to that [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.http.client.advanced.html#file-uploads).